# php access array from POST response

Tags: php

i use a php post to get the number of users in the telegram group

```
<?php
$post = array(
'chat_id'=>$chat_id);
$ch = curl_init("https://api.telegram.org/bot$tokken/getChatMembersCount?");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
header('Content-Type: text/html');
$posres = curl_exec($ch);
$data1 = json_encode($posres);
echo $data1;
?>
```

the response are array  :

```
{"ok":true,"result":3}
```

how can i access the result value i tried echo $data1[19]; this only give the index position value
thank you

Comment: Why do you think there would be an item in `$data1[19]`, the result just has a count of the users and nothing more (OK except for the `ok` value).

Comment: what if the response are {"ok":true,"result":33} then i get the same result 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is JSON, so you need to use `json_decode()` to convert it to a PHP array or object.

```
$data1 = json_decode($posres);
echo $data1->result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case Your response is array of object

`echo $data1['19']->result;` this should give 3 according to your question